# how to find some data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm new with NoSQL thing specifically mongodb. I have a collection

```
{
  "page1":{
            "content":"some content for page1",
            "pageId":"1" 
          },
  "page2":{
            "content":"some content for page2",
            "pageId":"2"
          }

}
```

I want to find the content and pageId for page1.
I tried something like

```
db.mycollection.find({"page1":{"pageId":"1"}})
db.mycollection.find({"pageId":"1"})
```

and i got result which is it doesn't satisfy my needs, specifically zero result.

thanks
Donquixote

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses dot notation to access nested objects. In order to find pageId, you should update your query as follows :

```
db.mycollection.find({"page1.pageId":"1"})
```

For more information read the followings :

- [Query Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)
- [Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/)

Answer (score 0):

This is all just JSON syntax which shouldn't be that different to what you see in python, ruby, perl etc. You want:

```
db.mycollection.find({ "page1.pageId": 1 })
```

This will match a document with a field "page1" containing a field of "pageId" with a value of 1.

```
db.mycollection.find({ page1: { pageId: 1 } })
```

That however would expect that the **whole** "page1" field exactly matched the subdocument you gave it, being { pageId: 1 }. This is not a match.

```
db.mycollection.find({ page1: { content: "some content for page 1", pageId: 1 } })
```

Is the explicit match for the subdocument, but likely not what you want in a query.

See the on-line [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) for more exaples

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your mongo shell:

```
db.mycollection.find({page1:{$exists:true}},{"page1.content":true,"page1.pageId":true,"_id":false}).pretty();
```

Comment: @Muddit Hi Muddit it worked but do have any idea how it will be applied in php using arrays?

Comment: I don't have idea how in PHP this can be implemented.